# A medium-sized compactification of the natural numbers

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers with the discrete topology.  Is there a compactification $X$ of $\mathbb{N}$, other than the Stone–Čech compactification $\beta \mathbb{N}$, in which every infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has at least two limit points?

In other words, does there exist a compact Hausdorff space $X$, not homeomorphic to $\beta \mathbb{N}$, having a countable dense discrete subset $A$ such that every infinite subset of $A$ has at least two limit points?

Motivation: $\beta \mathbb{N}$ has the property that for every infinite $B \subset \mathbb{N}$, the closure $\bar{B}$ is again  homeomorphic to $\beta \mathbb{N}$  (see Lemma 5 [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/stone-cech-compactification-of-the-integers-basic-facts/)).  In particular, $B$ has $2^\mathfrak{c}$ limit points.  Of course, $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is the "largest possible" compactification of $\mathbb{N}$.

On the other hand, if $X$ is first countable at any point $x$ of $X \setminus \mathbb{N}$, then there is a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ converging to $x$.  This sequence is thus an infinite set with only one limit point.  So any first countable compactification is "too small".

I am wondering what is in between.

(This came up while thinking about [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2202052/822).)

Comment: An example of size continuum in ZFC cannot be done: if $2^\omega < 2^{\mathfrak{t}}$ (where $\mathfrak{t}$ is the tower-invariant of the continuum), because then all compactifications of $\omega$ of size $\mathfrak{c}$ are sequentially compact. So some set theory will be involved to make a small example.See the article on countably and sequentially compact spaces in the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology (a great book!).

Answer (score 2):

Take two points $x,y\in\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, and let $X$ be the quotient of $\beta\mathbb{N}$ obtained by identifying $x$ and $y$.  You can see that $X$ is not homeomorphic to $\beta\mathbb{N}$, since $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of the subspace consisting of all its isolated points and $X$ is not.

Comment: Can you get one of a smaller cardinality? I'd like to see a compactification of cardinality $\mathfrak c$.

Comment: I would guess the answer is yes but I'm not sure at the moment.

Comment: @MikeMiller you could try a transfinite induction in $\beta \omega$, but then you can get a "countably-compact"-fication, not a compactification, as all closed subsets of $\beta\omega$ are too large.

Comment: @MikeMiller That cannot be done if $2^\omega < 2^{\mathfrak{t}}$ (where $\mathfrak{t}$ is the tower-invariant of the continuum), because then all compactifications of $\omega$ of size $\mathfrak{c}$ are sequentially compact. So some set theory will be involved to make a small example.See the article on countably and sequentially compact spaces in the Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology (a great book!).